# Can't call Raphael js module in auto_prepend

Tags: php

I have an `auto_prepend` file on my server.

It contains amongst more, the following:

```
<script src="../scripts/modules/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script>
  var this_line_fails = Raphael(0,0,100,100);
  //var overpaint_rectangle = overpaint_area.rect(0, 0, 10000, 10000, 0);
  //overpaint_rectangle.attr({fill: "red"});
  alert('hi');
</script>
```

But the problem is that in the `auto_prepend`, the line calling Raphael always fails, it doesn't fail in a regular file though. It is like there is something in the settings of the `auto_prepend` that is making it fail.

How can I call a Raphael module successfully in an `auto_prepend` file on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "auto_prepend", I assume you mean something like PHP's [`auto_prepend_file` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file). This is intended to be used to include and process a server-side script before the main file, not necessarily for prepending client-side content/script.

By auto-prepending a client-side script it's likely to be positioned incorrectly in the resulting page - outside of your `html` content.

Comment: well that's definitely in the direction, I have a div and raphael doesn't work if declared above it.

Comment: Apparently when in a non-append file, I must declare raphael within a <div> tag. Don't ask me why but that solves it. Thanks for pointing me on the right track.